# How can I glitch my goat out of the map?

Tags: goat-simulator

Can I somehow make the goat glitch out of the game map in Goat Simulator?

I'm aware [the goat can't die](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/355242/how-can-i-kill-my-goat), but is it possible to glitch it out of the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can make use of the traffic tunnels on either side of the road that crosses the map** to glitch out of the map.

- You can attach your goat to a vehicle that passes the road by licking it, and wait for the physics engine to glitch your bovine friend out of the end tunnel wall, or
- try to get it get hit by a vehicle just in front of those walls to force it out.